# Lazy computation inside IO monad

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to generate a infinite lazy stream of values from IO wrapped by WriterT. I'm using conduits to consume this stream and write it to a file. I'm well aware of the strictness of IO in its bind operator, so how could I produce this stream lazily having IO there?

If it is impossible, should I try to change to lazy ST?

```
import Data.Conduit
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.DList as DL

type Stream = WriterT (DL.DList String) IO ()

generator :: Stream
generator = do
    tell $ DL.singleton "something"
    generator

runStream :: Stream -> IO ()
runStream s = runResourceT $ stream s
    where stream s       = sourceStream s $$ sinkStream -- sinkStream just writes to a file
          sourceStream s = do w <- liftIO $ execWriterT s
                           CL.sourceList (DL.toList w)
```

Comment: Yes, why not just use lazy IO?

Comment: Why don't you simply rewrite your generator as `Source IO String`?

Comment: @DonStewart I just want to tinker with conduits to see how well the tackle IO :-)

Comment: @PetrPudlák Yeah, it was stupid my idea, the best thing is to write a Source directly with my infinite stream thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that nobody gave a full answer, I'll convert my comment into one. One of the biggest advantages of `conduit` is that it saves us from using lazy IO! Using a complicated `WriterT` goes against the idea. Instead, we should make `generator` a `Source` and then just plug it with a file `Sink`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

generator :: Monad m => Source m String
generator = replicateM_ 3 (yield "something\n")
    -- or `forever (...)` if you want an infinite loop

-- Reads Strings, converts them to ByteStrings and writes
-- to a file.
sinkStream :: MonadResource m => FilePath -> Sink String m ()
sinkStream file = mapInput BS.pack (const Nothing) (sinkFile file)

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT (generator $$ sinkStream "/tmp/output.txt")
```